# Duplicate Requests to a WCF Http service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, http

We have a desktop app which talks to the server via a number of WCF end points. We occasionally receive duplicate requests at some end points. We've spent a lot time examining why the client code might send duplicate requests we think this is pretty well locked down now. However, we continue to receive duplicate requests.

Could there be any reason, other than the client explicitly sending two requests, that we receive duplicate http requests? I've head some http clients automatically retry after a receiving a 500 result code, but I don't think this is the case for the .NET http client.

Comment: Are you using a load balancer in front of your service?

Comment: No, we have multiple web servers, but for various reasons it's the client that chooses which server to use, and then the session is "sticky", i.e. the client will always use the same server if it can.

Comment: I had the same issue. [This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/125411c3-b153-4602-b463-6cc7ec3e4367) helped me much.

Answer (score 0):

There is no retry logic built into the wcf stack, except for the bindings with msmq. I would therefore have to conclude that your client is sending a duplicate request.