# Duplicate Requests in Azure WCF Cloud Service

Tags: wcf, http, iis, azure, load-balancing

I have a WCF cloud service running on Azure. There is an interface exposed with two functions func1() and func2(). The issue I am facing is that I am getting multiple requests from my client application on one of the APIs.

Initially we thought its a bug in the client and the fact that we cannot get logs from client application (as its already in the market) made it even more difficult for us to analyze the issue.

I read a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15805863/duplicate-requests-to-a-wcf-http-service) and I thought the issue is similar to mine. The client application is coded in such a way that in a day only one call to functions happens each day. But I am getting around 60 calls within a span of few seconds. Client, in ideal conditions, will not send so many requests.

Can anyone help me out in this issue. Its really causing problem for us and we are not able to debug the issue. Here I am posting the IIS logs:

```html
2015-03-05 05:41:53 W3SVC1234567890 RD000D11111111 XX.XX.XX.XX POST /XYZ.svc - 443 - yy.yy.yy.yy HTTP/1.1 - - - abcd.cloudapp.net 200 0 0 1288 1244 825
2015-03-05 05:41:53 W3SVC1234567890 RD000D11111111 XX.XX.XX.XX POST /XYZ.svc - 443 - yy.yy.yy.yy HTTP/1.1 - - - abcd.cloudapp.net 200 0 0 1288 1244 943
2015-03-05 05:41:53 W3SVC1234567890 RD000D11111111 XX.XX.XX.XX POST /XYZ.svc - 443 - yy.yy.yy.yy HTTP/1.1 - - - abcd.cloudapp.net 200 0 0 1288 1223 462
2015-03-05 05:41:53 W3SVC1234567890 RD000D11111111 XX.XX.XX.XX POST /XYZ.svc - 443 - yy.yy.yy.yy HTTP/1.1 - - - abcd.cloudapp.net 200 0 0 1288 1220 550
2015-03-05 05:41:53 W3SVC1234567890 RD000D11111111 XX.XX.XX.XX POST /XYZ.svc - 443 - yy.yy.yy.yy HTTP/1.1 - - - abcd.cloudapp.net 200 0 0 1288 1223 489
2015-03-05 05:41:54 W3SVC1234567890 RD000D11111111 XX.XX.XX.XX POST /XYZ.svc - 443 - yy.yy.yy.yy HTTP/1.1 - - - abcd.cloudapp.net 200 0 0 1288 1220 492
2015-03-05 05:41:54 W3SVC1234567890 RD000D11111111 XX.XX.XX.XX POST /XYZ.svc - 443 - yy.yy.yy.yy HTTP/1.1 - - - abcd.cloudapp.net 200 0 0 1288 1223 643
2015-03-05 05:41:54 W3SVC1234567890 RD000D11111111 XX.XX.XX.XX POST /XYZ.svc - 443 - yy.yy.yy.yy HTTP/1.1 - - - abcd.cloudapp.net 200 0 0 1288 1220 587
2015-03-05 05:41:55 W3SVC1234567890 RD000D11111111 XX.XX.XX.XX POST /XYZ.svc - 443 - yy.yy.yy.yy HTTP/1.1 - - - abcd.cloudapp.net 200 0 0 1288 1220 591
2015-03-05 05:41:55 W3SVC1234567890 RD000D11111111 XX.XX.XX.XX POST /XYZ.svc - 443 - yy.yy.yy.yy HTTP/1.1 - - - abcd.cloudapp.net 200 0 0 1168 1414 851
2015-03-05 05:41:55 W3SVC1234567890 RD000D11111111 XX.XX.XX.XX POST /XYZ.svc - 443 - yy.yy.yy.yy HTTP/1.1 - - - abcd.cloudapp.net 200 0 0 1288 1220 408
2015-03-05 05:41:55 W3SVC1234567890 RD000D11111111 XX.XX.XX.XX POST /XYZ.svc - 443 - yy.yy.yy.yy HTTP/1.1 - - - abcd.cloudapp.net 200 0 0 1288 1220 392
2015-03-05 05:41:56 W3SVC1234567890 RD000D11111111 XX.XX.XX.XX POST /XYZ.svc - 443 - yy.yy.yy.yy HTTP/1.1 - - - abcd.cloudapp.net 200 0 0 1288 1223 507
2015-03-05 05:41:56 W3SVC1234567890 RD000D11111111 XX.XX.XX.XX POST /XYZ.svc - 443 - yy.yy.yy.yy HTTP/1.1 - - - abcd.cloudapp.net 200 0 0 1288 1223 390
2015-03-05 05:41:56 W3SVC1234567890 RD000D11111111 XX.XX.XX.XX POST /XYZ.svc - 443 - yy.yy.yy.yy HTTP/1.1 - - - abcd.cloudapp.net 200 0 0 1288 1223 404
2015-03-05 05:41:58 W3SVC1234567890 RD000D11111111 XX.XX.XX.XX POST /XYZ.svc - 443 - yy.yy.yy.yy HTTP/1.1 - - - abcd.cloudapp.net 200 0 0 1288 1223 621
2015-03-05 05:41:58 W3SVC1234567890 RD000D11111111 XX.XX.XX.XX POST /XYZ.svc - 443 - yy.yy.yy.yy HTTP/1.1 - - - abcd.cloudapp.net 200 0 0 1288 1223 594
2015-03-05 05:41:59 W3SVC1234567890 RD000D11111111 XX.XX.XX.XX POST /XYZ.svc - 443 - yy.yy.yy.yy HTTP/1.1 - - - abcd.cloudapp.net 200 0 0 1288 1223 544
2015-03-05 05:41:59 W3SVC1234567890 RD000D11111111 XX.XX.XX.XX POST /XYZ.svc - 443 - yy.yy.yy.yy HTTP/1.1 - - - abcd.cloudapp.net 200 0 0 1288 1223 444
2015-03-05 05:42:00 W3SVC1234567890 RD000D11111111 XX.XX.XX.XX POST /XYZ.svc - 443 - yy.yy.yy.yy HTTP/1.1 - - - abcd.cloudapp.net 200 0 0 1288 1223 656
2015-03-05 05:42:00 W3SVC1234567890 RD000D11111111 XX.XX.XX.XX POST /XYZ.svc - 443 - yy.yy.yy.yy HTTP/1.1 - - - abcd.cloudapp.net 200 0 0 1288 1223 453
2015-03-05 05:42:00 W3SVC1234567890 RD000D11111111 XX.XX.XX.XX POST /XYZ.svc - 443 - yy.yy.yy.yy HTTP/1.1 - - - abcd.cloudapp.net 200 0 0 1288 1223 484
2015-03-05 05:42:01 W3SVC1234567890 RD000D11111111 XX.XX.XX.XX POST /XYZ.svc - 443 - yy.yy.yy.yy HTTP/1.1 - - - abcd.cloudapp.net 200 0 0 1288 1223 500
2015-03-05 05:42:01 W3SVC1234567890 RD000D11111111 XX.XX.XX.XX POST /XYZ.svc - 443 - yy.yy.yy.yy HTTP/1.1 - - - abcd.cloudapp.net 200 0 0 1288 1223 393
```

Comment: Have you tried this in a non-Azure environment to see if you can reproduce the issue? Have you tried pushing the requests through Fiddler to see what's going on? I can imagine if your client is making async requests and there is a bug in your code it may well display this behaviour.

Comment: same problem here, I got some answers about having deployed the service in azure on two nodes... ok... so what? this behavior is weird. did you manager to find an workaround?